# Firebase email only sends to @GOOGLE.COM

Tags: android, email, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have no issues with the confirmation email of firebase when I use **@gmail.com**, but if I use **@hotmail.com** the email never arrives. Anyone knows why? I can't seem to find anything on the web about this.

This is the code to send the verification email:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

user.sendEmailVerification().addOnCompleteListener((task) {

      if(task.isSuccessful()){
            //Code
      }
});
```

Comment: Are you sure it is only Google? Did you try an other mailadres?

Comment: Same problem here. Another database works flawless.